# Render Image Programatically

Tags: 8

I want to create a new image field output to make it work with my lazy load script. For this I want the output to look like:

```
<img data-src="/sites/default/files/styles/lazy_load/image.jpg" src="/sites/default/files/styles/placholder/image.jpg" width="110" height"300" class="lazy">
```

To fix this I have this code:

```
function hook_preprocess_image(&$variables) {
    if ($variables['style_name'] == 'lazy_load') {
        /* @    -- Change src and add data-src */
        $datasrc = $variables['attributes']['src'];
        $src = str_replace('styles/lazy_load','styles/placeholder',$datasrc);
        $variables['attributes']['src'] = $src;
        $variables['attributes']['data-src'] = $datasrc;
        $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'lazy';
    }
}
```

This does what I want but...the image with the `placeholder` image_style is not rendered so it can not be found.

I also tried getting the right url via:

```
$style = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('image_style')->load('placeholder');
$url = $style->buildUrl($variables['uri']);
```

This again did give me the right URL but still the image is not rendered. How can I solve this problem?

### Update

I tried using the `hook_preprocess_image_style` like thfunction

```
hook_lazyload_preprocess_image_style(&$variables) {
    if ($variables['style_name'] == 'lazy_load') {
        // The image.factory service will check if our image is valid.
        $image = \Drupal::service('image.factory')->get($variables['uri']);
        if ($image->isValid()) {
            $logo_render_array = [
                '#theme' => 'image_style',
                '#width' => $image->getWidth(),
                '#height' => $image->getHeight(),
                '#style_name' => 'placeholder',
                '#uri' => $variables['uri'],
            ];
        }
    }
}
```

But still no succes. What I'm I missing here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: check if lazy load  lib loaded, and then set just *data-src* and *class*

Comment: I don't understand what the lazy load lib has to do with my question?

Comment: Try `hook_preprocess_image_style`, at this point the image style is built and can be loaded by `#uri`, see [template_preprocess_image_style](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21image%21image.module/function/template_preprocess_image_style/8.7.x)

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to tell a bit more about how to use the hook_preprocess_image. At what point to use it? Or do I use it instead of hook_preprocess_image?

Comment: At this point you still have the original `uri` variable to build the second image style.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the hook but unfortunately without succes. See my update question.

Comment: change "hook" to your theme or module name 
like "bootstrap_preprocess_image_style"

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I changed it to hook to make it more clear in the question in my real code hook is already replaced with the module name.